# Troubled with the use of ftell() and fseek() function

Tags: c, xterm

I have following C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    long n;
    char c;

    fp=fopen("RANDOM","W");

    while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putc(c,fp);
    }

    printf("No. of character entered = %1d\n",ftell(fp));
    fclose(fp);

    n=0L;

    while(feof(fp) == 0)
    {
        fseek(fp, n, 0);
        printf("Position of %c is %1d\n", getc(fp), ftell(fp));
        n=n+5L;
    }
    printf("\n");

    fseek(fp,-1L,2);
    do
    {
        putchar(getc(fp));
    }
    while(!fseek(fp,-2L,1));

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

This code is not showing any error. But when I run the code after giving input **ABCD...Z**, it says **segment fault, core dumped.** Where is the problem??

Answer (score 3):

Confident the seg fault is from calling `feof()` after the `fclose()`.  `fp` is closed at the point and should not be passed as an augment to another IO function.

Number of issues

1) Do not use uppercase `"W"`, but lowercase `"w"`.  Else undefined behavior (UB).

2) Use of `fopen("RANDOM","w")` truncates a file to zero length and writing, but not update.  Suggest use `fopen("RANDOM","r+")` "open text file for update (reading and writing)" or `fopen("RANDOM","w+")` which open for reading and writing and "truncate to zero length or create text file for update" @BLUEPIXY

3) `char c; ... while((c=getchar()) != EOF)` is wrong as the end-of-file condition will get flagged on some legitimate `char`.  Instead use `int c`.

4) No need for `fclose(fp);`  after `printf("No. of...`.

5) `while(feof(fp) == 0)` begin an infinite loop.  If anything use `if (feof(fp) == 0)`.  Although for learner's purposes, the test can be dropped.
5R) May this is OK.  Recommend checking result of `fseek(fp, n, 0);`

6) `printf("Position of %c is %1d\n", getc(fp), ftell(fp));` should use `"%ld"` and not `"%d"`.

7) Do not use `fseek(fp, n, 0);` and `fseek(fp,-1L,2);` but something like `fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_SET);`  or `SEEK_CUR SEEK_END`.

8) Without using the standard macros as mentioned above, unclear what the code's goal is for `fseek(fp,-1L,2);`

9) Suggest testing the result of `fseek(fp,-1L,2);`.

10) `printf("Position of %c is %1d\n", getc(fp), ftell(fp));` is a problem. (identified by @BLUEPIXY).  The *order* that `getc(fp)` and `ftell(fp)` is called is left to the compiler to choose.  Better to be explicit like `printf("Position of %c is ", getc(fp)); printf("%ld\n", ftell(fp));`.

---

If code is to truncate an existing file before writing, opening with `"w"` is good.  Rather than the remove the middle `fclose()`, consider `freopen(..., "r")`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  Agree on both your points.  Nice catch on the order of args to `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, add `fp=fopen("RANDOM","R")` after the first `fclose(fp)`.

You can't read from a file after closing it (neither can you read from it when it's opened only for writing).